# Best way to get nearest non-zero value from list

Tags: python

I have a list of values and I need to, given any arbitrary starting index, find the closest value which is non zero, if the value at the starting index is zero...

Here is what I have:

```
def getNearestNonZero(start_index):
    mylist = [4,2,6,7,3,0,0,9,4,2,5,8,1,7]
    val = mylist[start_index]
    if val == 0:
        loop_length = 0
        after = mylist[start_index+1:]
        before = mylist[:start_index]
        before =  before[::-1]
        print(before, after)

        if len(before) >= len(after):
            loop_length = len(before)
        else:
            loop_length = len(after)

        for i in range(loop_length):
            if i < len(before):
                before_val = before[i]
            if i < len(after):
                after_val = after[i]

            if before_val > 0:
                return before_val

            if after_val > 0:
                return after_val

    return val

result = getNearestNonZero(6)
print(result)

result = getNearestNonZero(5)
print(result)
```

> [0, 3, 7, 6, 2, 4] [9, 4, 2, 5, 8, 1, 7]
>
> 9
>
> [3, 7, 6, 2, 4] [0, 9, 4, 2, 5, 8, 1, 7]
>
> 3

What I do, is I first check to see if the value at the `start_index` is > 0. If it is, great, return it. If however, the value is zero, we need to find the closest non-zero, with a preference for before, rather than after...

To do this, I split `mylist` into two separate lists, `before` and `after`. If my start index is 6, `before` will now look like: `[4,2,6,7,3,0]` and after will look like: `[9,4,2,5,8,1,7]`.

Since I need the closest value to the `start_index`, I reverse my `before` list: `before = before[::-1]`

I then get the length of the longest of the two (`before` and `after`).

I then loop and check the value at each index of the two lists. The first one to have a value > 0 is returned and my work is done.

However, this feels very clunky and as if it can be done in a cleaner way.

Does anyone have any recommendations? What is the faster/cleaner/pythonic way for finding the nearest non-zero value in a list, given a starting index?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question here because **it has already been reposted on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172113/best-way-to-get-nearest-non-zero-value-from-list**

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple function that utilizes some numpy functions that will return the closest non-zero value.

```
def closest_non_zero(l, i):
    if l[i] > 0:
        return l[i]

    arr = np.array(l)
    non_zeros = np.nonzero(arr)[0]
    distances = np.abs(non_zeros - i)
    closest_idx = np.min(np.where(distances == np.min(distances)))

    return arr[non_zeros[closest_idx]]
```

Comment: nice solution with np (+1) but OP asked for before values first?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by first creating a list of all nonzero values (along with their indices) and then sort this list according to the distance of the index from `start_index` and return the closest one:

```
def closest_nonzero(lst, start_index):
    nonzeros = [(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x != 0]
    sorted_nonzeros = sorted(nonzeros, key=lambda x: abs(x[0] - start_index))
    return sorted_nonzeros[0][1]

lst = [4,2,6,7,3,0,0,9,4,2,5,8,1,7]
print(closest_nonzero(lst, 6))  # 9
print(closest_nonzero(lst, 5))  # 3
```

Comment: You got my upvote, however this is not giving prio to before values yet and you got some typos (function names). +1

Comment: Fixed the typo, but this does actually give prio to before values given that `sorted` is a stable sort, so the "before values" will come first.

Comment: I tried with this list and your function still returns 9 with input 6: lst = [4,2,6,7,3,0,0,0,9,4,2,5,8,1,7], the lst you are using has no prio order

Answer (score 0):

I have modified Jonas Adler version to consider the left item first. Credit goes to him though. (added a value to the tuple which is positive if left, negative if right). Seems to work.

```
def closest_nonzero(lst, start_index):
    nonzeros = [(i, x , start_index-i) for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x != 0]
    sorted_nonzeros = sorted(nonzeros, key=lambda x: abs(x[0] - start_index))
    return sorted_nonzeros[0][1]

lst = [4,2,6,1,0,0,0,7,4,2,5,8,1,7]

print(closest_nonzero(lst, 6))  # 1
print(closest_nonzero(lst, 5))  # 7
```